# fatel error is coming in getRow() function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pear

I am using this method to fetching the Rows from the database and showing on the `frontend` but when it execute it is giving a fatel error that is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRow() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Deshbandhu\class\tblOp.php on line 432

and the function code which I am using that is

```
 function getRowFields($fields,$where = NULL, $order = NULL){
    global $db; 
    $fields = ($fields) ? " $fields "           : " * ";
    $where  = ($where) ? " WHERE $where "       : "";
    $order  = ($order) ? " ORDER BY $order "    : " ORDER BY {$this->primaryKey} ";
    $sql    = "SELECT $fields FROM {$this->table} $where $order;"; // limit 0,1
    $res    =$db ->getRow($sql, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    echo $res; exit;
    if (DB::isError($res))
        return $this->raiseError($res);
    return $res;
}
```

and the defination of the getRow() are

```
function getRow($where = NULL, $order = NULL,$fields=NULL){
    global $db; 

   $sql    = $this->buildQuery(NULL, TBLOP_EXECUTE_SELECT, $where, $order,$fields);

    //echo $sql.'<br>';
    $res    = $db->getRow($sql, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

    if (DB::isError($res))
        return $this->raiseError($res);

    return $res;
}
```

this code is running on live server and not giving any error but when I execute it on local server it is showing error like this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `$db` variable, check your DB-initialization code, it's probably failing to connect to the database and is not checking for error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AdoDB for me, im using the same. Did you forget the Databasesettings? Should look liek that:

```
$db = ADONewConnection("mysql"); // eg 'mysql' or 'postgres'
$db->Connect("host", "user", "password", "table");
```

Comment: i am using this `$dsn = "mysql://".DB_USER.":".DB_PASS."@".DB_HOST."/".DB_DATABASE;`

Comment: you declare $dsn, but as object in your code, you use $db. And im not even sure if your declaration works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this problem before and I fixed it by repairing my tables.